# Simple javascript filter/search for multiple list instead of just one?

Tags: javascript, search

I have some simple code that allows filtering of list items and it works almost perfectly. The only issue is that the search box only searches the first UL, how do I make it search both?

Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    // Declare variables
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You start by using unique ID's and the same class

```
<ul id="myUL1" class="ul">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL2" class="ul">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then you modify the script to target all LI's, regardless of UL, as long as it has that class

```
function myFunction() {

  var input  = document.getElementById('myInput'),
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase(),
      li     = document.querySelectorAll(".ul li");

  // Loop through all list items, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var a = li[i].querySelector("a");

    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.querySelector to select the children of both lists:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var query = document.querySelector('#myInput').value;
  
  // this wil grab all <li> elements from all <ul> elements on the page
  // however, you will want to specify a unique attribute for only the elements you wish to include
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul > li');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i ++) {
    var el = elements[i];
    if (el.innerText.indexOf(query) !== -1)
      el.style.display = '';
    else
      el.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search">
<ul id="myUL" class="ul1">
  <li><a href="#">bob</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">rob</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">tom</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">mark</a></li>
</ul>

<ul id="myUL2" class="ul2">
  <li><a href="#">purse</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">cat</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">pencil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sharpner</a></li>
</ul>
```